# SharePoint Business Data Web Part custom

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts, webpart-connection

I'm currently working on a SharePoint website linked to an SQL Server database.

On one page, 1st part is a Business Data filter that sends information to the 2nd part, a Business data item, and the 3rd part, a Business data related list.
[You can see the page here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCbT1.png)

Any idea how Can I add a "Edit candidate" link in the Business data item Web part? And a "Add result" link in the Business data related list?

I just cannot figure it out. I'm quite new to SharePoint. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Business Data Item Webpart supports XSL file, so if you just want to add a link in your webparts then you can use XSLT file (In other terms, display templates) for this and customize the user interface including **Edit Candidate** and Add **Result link**.

For more details about Business Data Item Webpart, you can visit this link:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/business-data-item-web-part-in-sharepoint-2010/

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will give a try. Where can I find the link to the "edit" or "add" form, knowing that I have to pass the candidate ID as a parameter to get its information?

Comment: I believe that you have stored your data in a SharePoint list and you can use the same edit and add link which is used in SharePoint list.

Comment: Actually I didn't. I was working only with external content types. But I will try with external lists to see if it works with what you propose. Thanks a lot

Comment: If you are not using any External List then you will have to create custom pages for Add/Edit or else you can directly use it if you are going to save your external data into any external list. You can select any approach whichever is preferable for you.